# Generic numeric function using traits and `match`

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to build a generic formatting function that takes two integers `T` as nominator and denominator, and formats the fraction according to some simple rules.

I had a look at the `num` traits, however, still can't make it work. I'm already with much more verbose code than I wanted to so I thought it's time to ask for help.

```
extern crate num;
use num::{Integer,FromPrimitive};

fn format_rational<T>(n: T, d: T) -> String
    where T: Integer + FromPrimitive + fmt::Display
{
    let one: T = FromPrimitive::from_u16(1).unwrap();
    let ten: T = FromPrimitive::from_u16(10).unwrap();
    let hun: T = FromPrimitive::from_u16(100).unwrap();
    let tho: T = FromPrimitive::from_u16(1000).unwrap();

    let precision = match d {
        one => Some(1),
        hun => Some(2),
        tho => Some(3),
        _ => None,
    };

    match precision {
        Some(p) => format!("{:.*}", p, n as f32 / d as f32),
        None => format!("{} / {}", n, d),
    }
}
```

This errors with

```
non-primitive cast: `T` as `f32`
```

But when I change the first `format!` line to

```
Some(p) => format!("{:.*}", p, f32::from(n) / f32::from(d))
```

I get this error:

```
the trait bound `f32: std::convert::From<T>` is not satisfied
```

which I interpret as "From does not exist for type f32", which makes sense. How is `f32` possible here when the trait is `Num`, which implies `Eq`, which implies it should exclude floats? (as floats only implement `PartialEq`). Finally, is there a way to simply work with `From<T>`?

What am I missing? Or can the problem be solved in another (easier) way? Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid writing the `format!(...)` line? Otherwise, I don't see what you have to gain by writing a function. If you have, for example, two `i32` values, `a` and `b`, and a precision of `p`, you can simply write `format!("{:.*}", p, a as f32 / b as f32)`, done. Using `format!` directly allows you to have dissimilar types for `a` and `b` as well without adding more generic types and gives full control over the precision instead of limiting it to a hard coded list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Herohtar. I'm aware of this but the formatting functionality I want to build behaves a bit different. As in the code, I only want to use the line you mentioned when the denominator is in `[1,100,1000]`. Otherwise, show the fraction with `/`. Besides, I'm learning Rust and interested in solving this the generic way.

Comment: EDIT: found a solution. Posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it today. Are there better ways of doing this?

```
extern crate num;
use std::fmt;
use num::{ToPrimitive};

pub fn format_rational<T>(n: T, d: T) -> String
    where T: ToPrimitive + fmt::Display
{
    let precision = match d.to_usize().unwrap() {
        1 | 10 => Some(1),
        100 => Some(2),
        1000 => Some(3),
        _ => None,
    };

    match precision {
        Some(p) => format!("{:.*}", p, ToPrimitive::to_f32(&n).unwrap() / ToPrimitive::to_f32(&d).unwrap()),
        None => format!("{} / {}", n, d),
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no point to take something generic but use it as something not generic.

Comment: How would you build it? `T` represents any integer type. Can (or should) we replace `T` with something like `num::Integer`?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding some `unwrap`s, compared to your answer:

```
extern crate num;
use std::fmt;
use num::{ToPrimitive};

pub fn format_rational<T>(n: T, d: T) -> String
    where
        T: ToPrimitive + std::ops::Div + fmt::Display,
        <T as std::ops::Div>::Output: fmt::Display,
{
    let precision = match d.to_usize() {
        Some(1) | Some(10) => Some(1),
        Some(100) => Some(2),
        Some(1000) => Some(3),
        _ => None,
    };

    match precision {
        Some(p) => format!("{:.*}", p, n.div(d)),
        None => format!("{} / {}", n, d),
    }
}
```